# ValueError when applying pandas_udf to grouped spark Dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

Sample PySpark Dataframe: `join_df`

```
+----------+----------+-------+---------+----------+----------+
|        ID|        ds|      y|     yhat|yhat_upper|yhat_lower|
+----------+----------+-------+---------+----------+----------+
|    Ax849b|2021-07-01|1165.59| 1298.809| 1939.1261| 687.48206|
|    Ax849b|2021-07-02|1120.69| 1295.552| 1892.4929|   693.786|
|    Ax849b|2021-07-03|1120.69| 1294.079| 1923.0253|  664.1514|
|    Ax849b|2021-07-04|1120.69|1295.0399| 1947.6392|  639.4879|
|    Bz383J|2021-07-03|1108.71|1159.4934| 1917.6515| 652.76624|
|    Bz383J|2021-07-04|1062.77|1191.2385| 1891.9268|  665.9529|
+----------+----------+-------+---------+----------+----------+
```

- y - real value
- yhat - predicted value

```
final_schema =StructType([
  StructField('ID',IntegerType()),
  StructField('ds',DateType()),
  StructField('y',FloatType()),
  StructField('yhat',FloatType()),
  StructField('yhat_upper',FloatType()),
  StructField('yhat_lower',FloatType()),
  StructField('mape',FloatType())
  ])
```

I have created an `udf` and applied it on `ID`s using `applyInPandas` function.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_absolute_percentage_error
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType

@pandas_udf(final_schema, PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def gr_mape_val(join_df):
  
  mape = mean_absolute_percentage_error(join_df["y"], join_df["yhat"]) 
  join_df['mape'] = mape
  
  return join_df

df_apply = join_df.groupby('ID').applyInPandas(gr_mape_val, final_schema)
df_apply.show()
```

I made multiple efforts but still getting this error:
**ValueError**

> ValueError: Invalid function: pandas_udf with function type
> GROUPED_MAP or the function in groupby.applyInPandas must take either
> one argument (data) or two arguments (key, data).

I wonder, do I need to have pandas df as an argument in `gr_mape_val()` or it will spark df (as it is).
Couldn't figure out what am I doing wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need `@pandas_udf` when you use `applyInPandas`. Just comment that line and you'll be fine.

Comment: Commented the lines and changed schema to `StringType`  but now I have this error: ```PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'pyarrow.lib.ArrowTypeError: Expected a string or bytes dtype, got int32' ```

Comment: can you run `join_df.printSchema()`

Comment: root
 |-- CIS_ANONYM: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- ds: date (nullable = true)
 |-- y: float (nullable = true)
 |-- yhat: float (nullable = true)
 |-- yhat_upper: float (nullable = true)
 |-- yhat_lower: float (nullable = true)

Comment: I see, your `ID` column has type `IntegerType`, so ignore my comment about schema. revert it back to `IntegerType` and try again

Comment: Tried, still getting this error: ```ValueError: Invalid function: pandas_udf with function type GROUPED_MAP or the function in groupby.applyInPandas must take either one argument (data) or two arguments (key, data). ```